# How do I fill the area between the line and the axis with line segments in Graphics?

Tags: graphics

I want to draw a simple bending moment diagram:
[image]

I did not draw its exact graph by solving the curve, my aim is to make a **simple diagram** by the connection between line segments or curves.

The code and the results are as follows:

```
pts1 = {{0, 0}, {2, -3}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}};
pts2 = {{5, 1}, {8, 1}, {8, 0}};
pts3 = {{0, 0}, {8, 0}};
Graphics@{{Thick, Black, BSplineCurve[pts1], 
   Inset[Style["+", Red, 20], {2, -0.6}]}, {Thick, Black, Line[pts2], 
   Inset[Style["-", Red, 20], {6.5, 0.5}]}, {Thick, Black, 
   Line[pts3]}, Inset[Style["6.4KN\[CenterDot]m", 15], {2, -1.6}], 
  Inset[Style["8KN\[CenterDot]m", 15], {6.5, 1.3}]}
```

[image]

But I would like to know how to fill in the line between the curve and the axis as in the original graph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
{HatchFilling[90 Degree, 1, 15], 
 FilledCurve[{BSplineCurve[pts1], Line[pts2], Line[pts3]}]}
```

```
Graphics@{{{HatchFilling[90 Degree, 1, 15], 
    FilledCurve[{BSplineCurve[pts1], Line[pts2], Line[pts3]}]}, Thick,
    Black, BSplineCurve[pts1], 
   Inset[Style["+", Red, 20], {2, -0.6}]}, {Thick, Black, Line[pts2], 
   Inset[Style["-", Red, 20], {6.5, 0.5}]}, {Thick, Black, 
   Line[pts3]}, Inset[Style["6.4KN·m", 15], {2, -1.6}], 
  Inset[Style["8KN·m", 15], {6.5, 1.3}]}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, `HatchFilling` is not available in version 12.0, I'll update my version.